# is there any design view in razor view engine?

Tags: c#, android, .net, winforms

I have to make a mvc application, But got stuck whether to use Razor or Aspx engine. I have made many web application in aspx, so razor is new to me.
 I have not found any **DESIGN View** in Razor like we found in aspx ( **design and source**).

I have to make a **.net application** through which i can send **sms through An android mobile** connected **via Usb** to computer. Is there any code or api similar to send sms Like in Nokia Mobile AT Commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a traditional design view like there was for ASP. The closest thing you can get to it can be achieved in the steps below:

- Get Visual Studio 2013
- Install the [Web Essentials 2013](http://vswebessentials.com/) extension
- Open the `Browser Link Dashboard` from View > Other Windows
- Press the `View in Browser` button
- You should see Internet Explorer (or another browser) appear with your web application displayed. Also notice that browser now appears under the `Connections` group in the `Browser Link Dashboard` in Visual Studio. Go ahead and open the dropdown arrow next to the browser name. Select `Design Mode`
- Return to the browser, you will now be able to select elements in the page and modify things like text. Your changes should be reflected in the respective cshtml file. You can also modify the css or underlying html of the page through the browser's developer tools (F12) and sync them back to Visual Studio

It isn't nearly as convenient as the old ASP style design mode, and can get cumbersome when you start involving layouts, partial views, editor templates, display templates, etc. But it's about as good as it gets when it comes to realtime editing of Razor pages.

Answer (score 1):

There is no design view for creating Razor views.

If you are deciding between Razor or the ASPX view engine, I would highly recommend Razor.

Answer (score 0):

No, theres no design view for Razor unfortunately.  You have to run the app and use a browser to see changes to you page.  If you do decide to go with WebForms id recommend looking at how to do the MVP pattern with it.

Comment: Then how to check whether our design code is appropriate, suitable and Fit in Razor??

Comment: can you give me video or e book tutorial for MVC with ASPX view engine?

Answer (score 0):

I've found something similar to that.

I just accidentally  went to File -> Recently Closed Documents and I got something similar:

[image]

Now I have Design Split and Source modes:

[image]

I'm using VS2019 Community, version 16.8.2